# "Unexpected token: name (closeBootstrapDatepicker)" during a rails deployment

Tags: heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-5

When deploying a rails 5 application, I get this error:

```
remote:        Bundle completed (3.85s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        The latest bundler is 1.16.3, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler`
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.5.1
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        yarn install v1.5.1
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.0: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.0" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
remote:        warning " > webpack-dev-server@2.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 24.80s.
remote:        I, [2018-07-31T05:34:58.372842 #459]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_e0b626d68337f6bf487c3718057509da/public/assets/placeholder-d28a0c1aa165374509a6d251adb89aa4c9f688dd2da914d199252b60f278a3fd.png
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: name (closeBootstrapDatepicker). To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true).
remote:        /tmp/build_e0b626d68337f6bf487c3718057509da/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.10/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
r
```

My platform is heroku. How do I fix it?
This application used to deploy fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku push issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259494/heroku-push-issue)

Comment: Can you show us the JavaScript code around `closeBootstrapDatepicker`?

Comment: I have long lost my setup